# How to prevent servr::jekyll from hanging after run?

Tags: r, jekyll

I am trying to post a new file to my blog each day using the servr::jekyll function in R.

After each run the console hangs until I press 'esc' and then everything works. When I run my script in macs automator it fails because of this hanging. How can I force servr::jekyll() to simply run the command and return to the console?  This is the code and output

```
> servr::jekyll()
Configuration file: /Users/joshua/Downloads/knitr-jekyll-gh-pages/_config.yml
        Source: /Users/joshua/Downloads/knitr-jekyll-gh-pages
   Destination: /Users/joshua/Downloads/knitr-jekyll-gh-pages/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
  Generating... 
                done in 0.397 seconds.
Auto-regeneration: disabled. Use --watch to enable.
```

Then it just hangs... Ideal output would be:

```
 > servr::jekyll()
Configuration file: /Users/joshua/Downloads/knitr-jekyll-gh-pages/_config.yml
        Source: /Users/joshua/Downloads/knitr-jekyll-gh-pages
   Destination: /Users/joshua/Downloads/knitr-jekyll-gh-pages/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
  Generating... 
                done in 0.397 seconds.
Auto-regeneration: disabled. Use --watch to enable.
>
```

Notice the > at the bottom.

Comment: I had to set  daemon = TRUE and wrap the command in a try block.